# javac esta configurado e não compila .class

Tags: java

javac esta configurado mas não compila para .class

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem até uma flecha apontando o erro no console.

Answer (score 4):

O erro é claro: Não existe tipo **string** no java, o correto é **String**, o S é maiúsculo. O correto é:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: muito obrigado, sou iniciante e fiquei o dia todo parado neste erro, muito obrigado de certo aqui